# PostgreSQL 10: deleting foreign key locks selects

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to delete a table (called `incoming`) in a busy database with 100s of transactions per second. The table itself is empty (performed a `truncate table` before). If I try to do `drop table incoming` a lot of transactions on various other tables are [waiting](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) for `drop table` to finish - obviously not good.

I began deleting indexes, constrains and columns 1 by 1 to identify what is blocking the table deletion and got to a foreign key constraint that was causing the lock. Here's the 'final' `incoming` table schema:

```
create table incoming
(
    account_id integer
        constraint incoming_account_id_fkey
            references account
);
```

From the blocked queries (taking the `ticket` table below as an example) it doesn't look like the `account` table queries are blocked but the queries on `ticket` - a busy table that has a foreign key to the `account` table. Why would deleting a FK in `incoming` block queries in `ticket`?

Here's the outline again on the 3 tables:

- `incoming` - this is where the foreign key I want to delete lives (see schema below).
- `account` - foreign key reference table.
- `ticket` - busy table (select, insert, update, etc..) that has a foreign key constraint to `account`.

What I tried doing:

I tried disabling the triggers on the table: `ALTER TABLE incoming DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;` and making the FK DEFERRABLE: `ALTER TABLE incoming ALTER CONSTRAINT incoming_account_id_fkey DEFERRABLE;`. Didn't help.

Here's the output of the `pg_constraint`:

`SELECT conname, conindid::regclass, confrelid::regclass, * FROM pg_constraint WHERE conrelid = 'incoming'::regclass`:

[image: pg_constraint output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are implemented as system triggers in PostgreSQL.

This query shows you the triggers behind your foreign key constraint:

```
SELECT t.tgrelid::regclass AS table_name,
       t.tgname AS trigger_name,
       concat(
          CASE t.tgtype & 66 WHEN 2 THEN 'BEFORE ' WHEN 64 THEN 'INSTEAD OF ' ELSE 'AFTER ' END,
          CASE WHEN t.tgtype & 4 > 0 THEN 'INSERT' END,
          CASE WHEN t.tgtype & 8 > 0 THEN 'DELETE' END,
          CASE WHEN t.tgtype & 16 > 0 THEN 'UPDATE' END
       ) AS fires,
       f.proname AS trigger_function
FROM pg_trigger AS t
   JOIN pg_proc AS f ON t.tgfoid = f.oid
   JOIN pg_constraint AS c ON t.tgconstraint = c.oid
WHERE c.conname = 'incoming_account_id_fkey';

 table_name |         trigger_name         |     fires     |   trigger_function   
------------+------------------------------+---------------+----------------------
 account    | RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_62074 | AFTER DELETE  | RI_FKey_noaction_del
 account    | RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_62075 | AFTER UPDATE  | RI_FKey_noaction_upd
 incoming   | RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_62076 | AFTER INSERT  | RI_FKey_check_ins
 incoming   | RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_62077 | AFTER UPDATE  | RI_FKey_check_upd
(4 rows)
```

You see that two of these triggers are defined on the target table, `account`.

If you drop table `incoming`, that will also drop the foreign key constraint and consequently drop the triggers on `account`, which requires a short `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on `account`.

That should not be disruptive, but it seems that you are running long transactions that involve `account`. Now the `DROP TRIGGER` on `account` has to queue behind the currently active transactions that hold locks on `account`, and all later transactions have to queue behind the `DROP TRIGGER`, which is what you observe.

You will have to find a time when there are no long running transactions involving `account`, then your `DROP TABLE` will finish quickly without blocking other sessions.

**Side remark:** choose `bigint` rather than `integer` for artificial primary key columns.